# Using SQL Server 2008, how to join two tables with same column names, but different datatypes

Tags: sql, join, types, alter

I have two tables, one is a table named `tree2009` and another `tree2012`.

`Tree2009` has a total of 3657 rows, and has the columns:

```
  classid(bigint, not null)
  dbh(decimal(3,0),null)
  zone(nvarchar(3), null)
  inspect(nvarchar(10),null).
```

`Tree2012` is an updated table, 3839 rows, and has columns:

```
  classid(bigint, not null) 
  dbh (decimal(15,6), null)
  zone(nvarchar(254), null)
  inspect(datetime,null).
```

The format of `tree2012` is the preferred one, so I would like to convert the datatypes and structure of `dbh`, `zone`, `inspect` to the 2009 format, then **COMBINE** the tables based on the common column: `classid`.

Is this possible given the difference in rows? Sorry if I did not explain anything properly as I am new to this.

Comment: what do you mean by **COMBINE**? `MERGE` The rows in `Tree2009` into `Tree2012`? get a third table with the `UNIQUE VALUES`?

Comment: I would like a third table, which merges all the records based on CLASSID. At the same time, I would like the extra records (as the 2012 table has more records) to be included in this table. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say combine, I assume you want a `UNION`, you could create a new table with both sets:

```
SELECT classid
     , dbh
     , zone
     , inspect
INTO Trees
FROM Tree2012
UNION 
SELECT classid
     , CAST(dbh AS DECIMAL(15,6))
     , CAST(zone AS NVARCHAR(254))
     , CAST(inspect AS DATETIME)
FROM Tree2009
```

That `UNION` should be `ALL` if you want to just combine both sets (disregarding duplicates) just can't post it that way due to firewall issue, `UNION` will check for and remove duplicate lines between the two sets and is therefore slower.

You could also use `INSERT` if you just wanted to keep Tree2012:

```
INSERT INTO Tree2012
    SELECT classid
         , CAST(dbh AS DECIMAL(15,6))
         , CAST(zone AS NVARCHAR(254))
         , CAST(inspect AS DATETIME)
    FROM Tree2009
```

You don't need to `CAST()` every data type, ie zone in your example going from shorter nvarchar to longer nvarchar.

If you have overlapping classID's and the values for the same classID are different in each table then you might be wanting to `JOIN` and have multiple columns for each year:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Classid,b.Classid)'ClassID'
      , a.dbh 'dbh-2012'
      , a.zone 'zone-2012'
      , a.inspect 'inspect-2012'
      , b.dbh 'dbh-2009'
      , b.zone 'zone-2009'
      , b.inspect 'inspect-2009'
INTO NewTable
FROM Tree2012 a
FULL JOIN Tree2009 b
   ON a.Classid = b.Classid
```

Comment: I am sorry, I should have stated I wanted a third new table to output the records. CLASSID should be used to JOIN the tables I guess? I'm not sure if JOIN or UNION would be the better option to "combine" (I don't know what other word to use other than "combine") the tables.

Comment: Check out the updated answer, added `INTO` portion.  What would your new table look like if you were going to use the Classid to `JOIN` the tables?

Comment: well classID would be the column that shares unique values right? therefore, the tables should be joined based on this column.

Comment: the 2012 table has more rows, so these additional rows would be added on top of the 2009 rows. therefore the new, third table should theoretically have 3839 rows.

Comment: So, when a classID is in both tables, for that classId you'd have 2 of each field?  Or are the values identical in both tables when the classID is the same?

Comment: the values would be identical, based off the classID

Comment: So use the first query above, as it's written, it will remove duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks GOAT! you've been most helpful!

Comment: Consider hitting the checkmark by this answer to mark your question as solved.